Applying De Morgans on Product of Sums
I want to write the Product of Sums from of the boolean function
$$F(A, B, C) = (A*B) + (A'*A) + (B'*C)$$
I can cancel out $(A'*A)$ and then I'm wondering how I can apply De Morgans law on $$(AB)\cup (B'C)$$
Is it even valid? I just need to get it into the form $(a+b)*(c+d)$ i think
EDIT:
My attempt:
$(A\cap B)\cup(B'\cap C) = ((A\cap B)\cup B')\cap ((A\cap B)\cup C) = (A\cup B')\cap (A\cup C) \cap (C\cup B) $

There maybe a shorter path to reach it, but here it goes one...
\begin{align}
AB + B'C
&= (AB + B')(AB + C)\\
&= (A + B')(B + B')(A + C)(B + C)\\
&= (A + B')(A + C)(B + C)\\
&= (A + B')(B + C)A + (A + B')(B + C)C\\
&= A(B + C) + (A + B')C\\
&= AB + AC + B'C\\
&= (A + B')(B + C). 
\end{align}
If you have trouble justifying some passage, let me know.

Another way to go see that $AB+B'C=AB+AC+B'C$ (which takes most of the steps above), is to show that $(AB+B'C)AC = AC$ (essentially use distributivity), and use that in Boolean algebra (or any lattice), if $XY=Y$, then $X+Y=X+XY=X$.

I got something very similar: $(A+B')(A+C)(C+B)$. Is this equivalent to yours?
Edit: its clear that its not

PLease look at my edit, can you see where I went wrong?

@user832075 Aside the notational inconsistency of going from $*$ to $\cap$, etc, everything is ok. It just can be simplified e bit more, getting the expression in my answer. In fact, you can notice that that is the expression I have in the third line of the aligned environment.

Ah, ok, just noticed the first comment, to which the answer is YES, which I referred to in my previous comment. However, since I have a shorter expression, mine one is preferable ($(A+C)$ in the expression is redundant, like $X1$, which is just $X$, just not obvious).
